# Clone functionality for APFS

Tags: clonezilla, clone, apfs

**2022 UPDATE:**  Clonezilla supports the APFS file system

I understand that Clonezilla does not list APFS as a supported file system.  It is important to me to be able to create a clone back of a disk so that the many of work can be restored should there be a failure or significant user error.

I have enjoyed Clonezilla's ability to back Ubuntu and Windows drives and restore them quickly.  Backups are kept to a minimal size on disk. I would like to be able to do this with a Mojave APFS disk.  What options (methods) exist that approach Clonezilla functionality?   Any best practices are appreciated: thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The "sector-by-sector" copy option should always work:

From [clonezilla.org](https://clonezilla.org/):

> For unsupported file system, sector-to-sector copy is done by `dd` in Clonezilla.

That's the option

```
[ ] -q1    Force to use sector-by-sector copy (supports all filesystem, but inefficient)
```

in [expert mode](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone/advanced/05-advanced-param.php) (second screenshot).

Comment: The disk is 240GB of which 20GB is used.  Will the resulting image be ~240GB?

Comment: Yes, it will be the same size.